# Null error after moving file to Standard Assets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I have working project but everything is out off standard assets. So I need to move this all folder and items to standard assets folder. When i move my all file and folder to standard assets, it give me null reference error.

I have a name space in my project and When I try to access this name space it's give me null error.

Here is my name space code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
  public interface IInputDetector
  {
    InputDirection? DetectInputDirection();
 }

  public enum InputDirection
 {
    Left, Right, Top, Bottom

  }
}
```

and here code to get access it

```
IInputDetector inputDetector = null;
```

and in start method

```
void Start(){
   inputDetector = GetComponent<IInputDetector>();
 }
```

in Update method it gives me error

```
var inputDirection = inputDetector.DetectInputDirection(); // Line 222
```

Error is like this..

**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ControllerMovement.DetectJumpOrSwipeLeftRight () (at Assets/Scripts/ControllerMovement.cs:222)
ControllerMovement.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ControllerMovement.cs:106)**

Line 22 is above var line..

and 106 line is from method which I am calling in Update() method.

like

```
void Update(){
  DetectJumpOrSwipeLeftRight(); // line 106
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have an object of type ControllerMovement which is null when DetectJumpOrSwipeLeftRight is called on it. The code snippets are, however, insufficent to check why this is the case. You should at least show what detectInputs() is doing, since the error is happening there.

Comment: ohh sorry for this  I am calling DetectJumpOrSwipeLeftRight(); in Update().

Comment: ContollerMovement is my class name, it pointing me on this line "var inputDirection = inputDetector.DetectInputDirection(); // Line 222" @Nebr

Comment: Where is the DetectInputDirection() function that should be inside the IInputDetector?

Comment: yes, DetectInputDirection() returns value like "LeftSwipe", "RightSwipe" , "Top and Bottom" from namespace, so when user swipe in any direction, I can check it (left == left) or not. @Alox

Comment: I never used an interface before but how does inputDetector find the function DetectInputDirection()? I'm used to having a class and when using that class you'd use one of the classes functions/members like DetectInputDirection()... But in your inputDetector interface, there is no such thing? Right? And that's where I think your getting a null reference from.

Comment: @Alox: You can implement instances of interfaces. For example, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx. Also, a NullReferenceException is a run-time exception. An incorrect implementation of an interface would lead to a compiler error.

Comment: @Nebr Okay, thanks! I've never been too good at understanding when certain errors occur with what their naming conventions are.

To be fair though, I was only trying to find a different solution to his error than yours. My main instinct was that there was an error with GetComponent<IInputDetector>() which would indicate that the gameobject didn't have the interface attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your object `inputdetector` in line 222 seems to be null. Calling `DetectInputDirection()` on a null object will lead to a `NullReferenceException`.

Since inputdetector is set to null at the beginning, and is only set to a different value by method `Start()`, there are two possible options:

1.) `Start()` is not called before line 222 is reached, so `inputdetector` is still null.

2.) `Start()` is called, but `GetComponent<IInputDetector>()` yields null.

From the current code snippets, it is not possible to say which one is actually happening.

Comment: I think 1) is not possible because, obviously Start() comes before Update(), Now we can focus on second.

Comment: Well, it is not obvious for me since I can't see when Start() is called. You can do this by setting a breakpoint at the line inputDetector = GetComponent<IInputDetector>(); and check which value is returned by the method. Also, it can be useful to show what GetComponent() is actually doing.

Comment: I don't Know why, but I put out all file and folder from standard assets and its work now.

Comment: Well, that's fine. Still you should never make a call like inputDetector.DetectInputDirection() without checking in advance if inputDetector is null. Always add something like if(inputDetector != null) and handle the case if it is null (e.g. like returning some error).

Comment: yes thanks, for this. I do same and this little thing filled null getcomponent<>(); with value.